# Using paintComponent() on a JFrame canvas being altered by a separate GUI

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paintcomponent, jcomponent

I am trying to make a JComponent application which uses two JFrames, one frame with alterable sliders and textfields for the graphical display of a firework on the second. When the "fire" button is pressed, a rendering of the firework should appear. However, I have found through placing strategic print statements, that my paintComponent() method does not run even though the conditional statement wrapping the code is satisfied. I have also double checked all of my other methods to ensure that correct values are generated at the correct times. After looking through all of the JComponent literature and questions I could find, I'm afraid I cannot get it to work - this problem is most likely derived from my lack of familiarity with the library. That being said, any advice no matter how rudimentary, will be much appreciated. Abridged code is below:

*The swing timer may also be the issue for I am not sure if I have used it correctly

[fireworksCanvas.java]

```
    public class fireworkCanvas extends JComponent implements ActionListener{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private ArrayList<Ellipse2D> nodes = new ArrayList<Ellipse2D>();
private ArrayList<Line2D> cNodes = new ArrayList<Line2D>();
private ArrayList<QuadCurve2D> bCurves = new ArrayList<QuadCurve2D>();
private int[] arcX; 
private int[] arcY;
private Color userColor;
private Random rand = new Random();
private int shellX, shellY, fType, theta, velocity;
private Timer timer;
private int time;
private double g = -9.8; //gravity in m/s
public boolean explosivesSet;

public fireworkCanvas() {
    time = rand.nextInt(3000) + 2000;
    timer = new Timer(time, this); // 5 seconds
    timer.start();
    fType = 0;
}

@Override 
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    if (explosivesSet) {
        System.out.println("fType" + fType);
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawPolyline(arcX, arcY, arcX.length);

        for (Ellipse2D e : nodes) {
            System.out.println("painting nodes"); // NEVER PRINTS
            g.setColor(userColor);
            g.fillOval(shellX + (int) e.getX(), shellY + (int) e.getY(), (int) e.getWidth(), (int) e.getHeight());
        }
        for (Line2D l: cNodes) {
            System.out.println("painting cNodes"); // NEVER PRINTS
            g.setColor(determineColor("l"));
            g.drawLine(shellX + (int) l.getX1(), shellY + (int) l.getY1(), shellX + (int) l.getX2(), shellY + (int) l.getY2());
        }
        for (QuadCurve2D c: bCurves) {
            System.out.println("painting curves"); // NEVER PRINTS
            g.setColor(determineColor("c"));
            g2D.draw(c);
        }
    }
}

public Color determineColor(String type) {

    // returns color
}

public void setExplosives() {

    if (fType != 5 && fType != 0) {

        nodes.clear(); // clears three array lists with FW components 
        cNodes.clear(); // these are the components to paint for the
        bCurves.clear(); // firework explosion graphic
        setArc(); // stores path of shell for a polyLine to be drawn

        // builds and generates components for FW based on type chosen (fType)
        setExplosivesSet(true);
        repaint();
    }
}

public void setArc() {
    // builds int[] for shellX, shellY
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     // nothing is here??
     // should I use the action performed in some way?
}
```

[GUI.java]

```
    public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ChangeListener, ItemListener, MouseListener{

private static JFrame canvasFrame = new JFrame("Canvas");

private fireworkCanvas canvas = new fireworkCanvas();
private Choice fireworkChooser = new Choice();
private JSlider launchAngle = new JSlider();
private JSlider velocity = new JSlider();
private JSlider r = new JSlider();
private JSlider g = new JSlider();
private JSlider b = new JSlider();
private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
private JButton button = new JButton("Fire!");
private JLabel launchLabel = new JLabel("Launch Angle ");
private JLabel velocityLabel = new JLabel("Velocity ");
private JLabel rLabel = new JLabel("Red ");
private JLabel gLabel = new JLabel("Green ");
private JLabel bLabel = new JLabel("Blue ");
public static int fHeight = 500;
public static int fWidth = 500;

public GUI() {

    this.add(panel);
    panel.add(button);
    panel.add(fireworkChooser);
    panel.add(launchAngle);
    panel.add(launchLabel);
    panel.add(velocity);
    panel.add(velocityLabel);
    panel.add(r);
    panel.add(rLabel);
    panel.add(g);
    panel.add(gLabel);
    panel.add(b);
    panel.add(bLabel);

    addActionListener(this);
    BoxLayout bl = new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    setLayout(bl);

    fireworkChooser.addItemListener(this);
    launchAngle.addChangeListener(this);
    velocity.addChangeListener(this);
    r.addChangeListener(this);
    g.addChangeListener(this);
    b.addChangeListener(this);
    button.addActionListener(this);

    fireworkChooser.add("Firework 1");
    fireworkChooser.add("Firework 2");
    fireworkChooser.add("Firework 3");
    fireworkChooser.add("Firework 4");
    fireworkChooser.add("Super Firework");

    launchAngle.setMinimum(1);
    launchAngle.setMaximum(90);
    velocity.setMinimum(1);
    velocity.setMaximum(50);
    r.setMinimum(0);
    r.setMaximum(255);
    g.setMinimum(0);
    g.setMaximum(255);
    b.setMinimum(0);
    b.setMaximum(255);  

}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(600, 200);
}

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

    // sets FW variables
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == button) {
        canvas.setfType(fireworkChooser.getSelectedIndex()+1);
        canvas.setExplosives();
        canvas.repaint();
        canvas.setExplosivesSet(false);
        System.out.println("button fired");
    }
}

public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    GUI gui = new GUI();
    gui.pack();
    gui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    gui.setVisible(true);
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    fireworkCanvas canvas = new fireworkCanvas();
    canvasFrame.pack();
    canvasFrame.add(canvas);
    canvasFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    canvasFrame.setVisible(true);
    canvasFrame.setSize(fWidth, fHeight);
    canvasFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}


}
```

Comment: Remove `setExplosivesSet(false);` from your paintComponent method.  You have no control over how often paintComponent is called;  it may be called many times per second in response to various operating system events.  Painting methods should never modify state.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense - I have moved the `setExplosivesSet(false); ` to actionPerformed() in the GUI.java class - which should work I believe - yet, to my demise, it still does not.

Comment: You are never adding anything to the `nodes`, `cNodes`, and `bCurves` lists, and you are not initializing `arcX` and `arcY`, so there is nothing to paint.  You probably wanted to do all that work in `actionPerformed`, which is invoked by your Timer each time the Timer’s duration passes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all:

```
public fireworkCanvas()
```

Class names should start with an upper case character. All the other classes in your code follow this rule. Learn by example.

```
private Choice fireworkChooser = new Choice();
```

Choice is an AWT component don't mix AWT components in a Swing application. Use a `JComboBox`.

> that my paintComponent() method does not run

```
fireworkCanvas canvas = new fireworkCanvas();
canvasFrame.pack();
canvasFrame.add(canvas);
```

You add the canvas to the frame AFTER you pack() the frame, so the size of the canvas is (0, 0) and there is nothing to paint.

The canvas should be added to the frame BEFORE the pack() and you should implement `getPreferredSize()` in your FireworkCanvas class so the pack() method can work properly.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for the basics and working examples to get you started.

Comment: I believe you meant JComboBox, not JCheckBox.